# Export Datalist to PDF with restricted rows per Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I am trying to export SqlData to pdf,for that i am trying to get data list to print preview.I have followed this example.http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/04/how-to-export-gridview-data-to-pdf.html here grid view data Displayed.But I have done some modification and tried to to take data on DataList.Now every thing works fine,I am able to take print preview of DataList.Only one problem is there,I want to restrict number of data display per page..Like i just want to Restrict 10Row per single page of pdf.Any one have idea how to achieve such functionality?

In short i need a page break functionality on exported pdf, [here](http://tempsend.com/D675A96A1D) is pdf i am getting currently

Sorry for if my question is too simple,But i am newbie on Asp.Net

Thanks

Comment: how will you determine the records or data to show on page, mean to say how will you set number of records to display per page?

Comment: I am having unique id on my db,on base of that unique id i am determining

Comment: dear it will depends on how you are displaying the data.. can you please attach the pdf with data so that i can answer to it more accurately.

Comment: @raman hi! please check updated question, i have put pdf url

Answer (score 1):

The approach show on that link is bit simpler but you can modify that to resolve your problem. Here is a bit of code:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace RowsCountSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4))
            {
                var pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream("Test.pdf", FileMode.Create));
                pdfDoc.Open();

                var table1 = new PdfPTable(3);
                table1.HeaderRows = 2;
                table1.FooterRows = 1;

                //header row 
                var headerCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("header"));
                headerCell.Colspan = 3;
                headerCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                table1.AddCell(headerCell);

                //footer row 
                var footerCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("footer"));
                footerCell.Colspan = 3;
                footerCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                table1.AddCell(footerCell);

                //adding some rows 
                for (int i = 0; i < 70; i++)
                {
                    //adds a new row
                    table1.AddCell(new Phrase("Cell[0], Row[" + i + "]"));
                    table1.AddCell(new Phrase("Cell[1], Row[" + i + "]"));
                    table1.AddCell(new Phrase("Cell[2], Row[" + i + "]"));

                    //sets the number of rows per page
                    if (i > 0 && table1.Rows.Count % 7 == 0)
                    {
                        pdfDoc.Add(table1);
                        table1.DeleteBodyRows();
                        pdfDoc.NewPage();
                    }
                }

                pdfDoc.Add(table1);
            }

            //open the final file with adobe reader for instance. 
            Process.Start("Test.pdf");
        }
    }
}
```